# Bitcoin BTC wallet receive addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, buy-bitcoins, address-generation, crypto-2.0

I want to create 100 to 500 to 1000 BTC receive addresses. It should not expire. Is it possible ? Is it possible in Bitcoin core ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with json-rpc interface and one-time script.

1. Enable json-rpc port by changing bitcoin.conf used by your Bitcoin Core (usually `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`).

https://ma.ttias.be/enable-the-rpc-json-api-with-password-authentication-in-bitcoin-core/

2. Start bitcoind/bitcoin core.
3. Unlock your wallet using RPC [**walletpassphrase**](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/walletpassphrase) with timeout parameter like 600 or greater.
4. Obtain new address using RPC [**getnewaddress**](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/getnewaddress). This function creates new receive address under the same account(~wallet).
5. Write the returned string into the TXT file with appending to the existing list of addresses.

This is to be done via simple python script and `for i in range(0, 500):` loop.

Use library such as [**python-bitcoinrpc**](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) to easily connect to your json-rpc.

Funds send to any of these addresses you've generated and saved to a TXT file joined to the available wallet balance and will be available to spend in a transaction from the interface.